# Use AutoMapper to convert relational dto models to polymorphic domain models

Tags: .net-core, automapper

In my database I have a base table with 2 detail tables, each record in the base table will only have one detail record.  I'm trying to map these 3 tables to two domain models that inherit from the shared base domain model.  This is commonly called Table Per Type inheritance in EntityFramework, but it's not implemented in EntityFrameworkCore.

My dto models look like

```
public class SourceBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
   public SourceA A {get;set;}
   public SourceB B {get;set;}
}

public class SourceA
{
    public string ValueA {get;set;}
}

public class SourceB
{
    public string ValueB {get;set;}
}
```

My desired domain models look like

```
public class TargetBase
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class TargetA : TargetBase 
{
    public string ValueA {get;set;}
}

public class TargetB : TargetBase
{
    public string ValueB {get;set;}
}
```

How do I set up my mappings to accomplish this?

---

My most successful attempt has been:

```
CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetBase>().ConvertUsing<CustomTypeConverter>();
CreateMap<SourceA, TargetA>();
CreateMap<SourceB, TargetB>();
```

with the CustomTypeConverter:

```
public class CustomTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceBase, TargetBase>
{
    public TargetBase Convert(SourceBase source, TargetBase destination, ResolutionContext context)
   {
       if (source.A == null)
       {
           return context.Mapper.Map<SourceB, TargetB>(source.B);
       }
       else if (source.B == null)
       {
           return context.Mapper.Map<SourceA, TargetA>(source.A);
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

Which correctly gives me the TargetA or TargetB type, but none of the TargetBase values are mapped.

Comment: See [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html). But that's based on the source type, not on some condition, so you'll have to workaround that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying :) The rest is up to you.

Comment: "The rest" is my entire question though.

Comment: You just need to find the previous solutions. There's nothing built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found for this is to use `ConstructUsing` and `AfterMap` to avoid recursion:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetBase>().ConstructUsing(x => Convert(x)).AfterMap(Transform);
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceA, TargetA>();
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceB, TargetB>();
        });

        var src = new SourceBase
        {
            Id = 3,
            Value = "Asd",
            A = new SourceA
            {
                ValueA = "Qwe"
            }
        };
        var a = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceBase, TargetBase>(src);
        a.Dump(); // Code for LinqPad to show the result
    }

    public static TargetBase Convert(SourceBase source)
    {
        if (source.A == null)
        {
            return new TargetB();
        }
        else if (source.B == null)
        {
            return new TargetA();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void Transform(SourceBase source, TargetBase target)
    {
        if (source.A == null)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceB, TargetB>(source.B, (TargetB)target);
        }
        else if (source.B == null)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceA, TargetA>(source.A, (TargetA)target);
        }
    }
}

public class SourceBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
   public SourceA A {get;set;}
   public SourceB B {get;set;}
}

public class SourceA
{
    public string ValueA {get;set;}
}

public class SourceB
{
    public string ValueB {get;set;}
}

public class TargetBase
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class TargetA : TargetBase 
{
    public string ValueA {get;set;}
}

public class TargetB : TargetBase
{
    public string ValueB {get;set;}
}
```

You can obviously put the conversion methods into a class of their own

Comment: That's interesting, but because the mapping happens in two steps, AM is unaware of what's going on, so you have to give up validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways, but it can work almost the way you tried it.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetBase>().ConvertUsing(s=>Mapper.Map(s, s.A == null ? (TargetBase)new TargetB() : new TargetA()));
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetA>().ForMember(d=>d.ValueA, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.A.ValueA));
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetB>().ForMember(d=>d.ValueB, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.B.ValueB));
});
```

The MapFroms are not required if you follow [the naming convention](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html) or use [an extension method](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7).

Comment: This works for my simplified example, but as I add more properties I need to explicitly map them.  I'd like to avoid maintaining this mapping.


Regarding naming conventions, it's worth noting that I'm not flattening anything.  I'm mapping 3 classes to 3 classes.  My change is adding inheritance to the target that doesn't exist in the source.

Comment: That's not possible. And I've explained how you can avoid the MapFrom-s. I don't see a better way at the moment. Giving up validation is unacceptable as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar answer to Lucian's.  I prefer this as it makes it explicit that its choosing a specific derived class mapping but effectively its the same answer.

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetBase>().ConvertUsing(s => s.A == null ? (TargetBase)Mapper.Map<SourceBase, TargetB>(s) : Mapper.Map<SourceBase, TargetA>(s));
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetA>().ForMember(d => d.ValueA, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.A.ValueA));
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceBase, TargetB>().ForMember(d => d.ValueB, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.B.ValueB));
        });
```